# Replace javascript "with" statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code comes from [jquery.highlight](http://johannburkard.de/resources/Johann/jquery.highlight-5.js). It uses the deprecated 'with' statement in line 3 and I've been trying to figure out how to refactor it with no success. I'd be happy with a javascript or jQuery solution.

```
jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function() {
    return this.find("span.highlight").each(function() {
        with (this.parentNode) {
            replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
            normalize();
        }
    }).end();
};
```

Here is my attempt but it chokes on  tags and presumably any content already wrapped in an element with a "Node was not found" error.

```
jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function () {
    return this.find("span.highlight").each(function () {
        var el = this.parentNode;
        el.replaceChild(el.firstElementChild.firstChild, el);
        el.normalize();
    }).end();
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is not equal to that `el` you're introducing, which is `this.parentNode`. The `with` statement only introduces the properties (and methods) from the object as local bindings, it does not affect `this`. Your code should be

```
var el = this.parentNode;
el.replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
el.normalize();
```

or just

```
this.parentNode.replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
this.parentNode.normalize();
```

Not sure where you've got that `.firstElementChild` from.

Comment: So very close and yet so far away. Thanks a bunch. `.firstElementChild` was me trying to operate on `this`.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `el` as a raw DOM object. You need to either define it as a jQuery object or use it in one later:

```
var el = $(this).parent();
```

Or

```
var el = this.parentNode;
$(el).doStuff();
```